# How to change the focus line of a TTabControl aligned to bottom?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

How to move the *focus line* of a `TTabControl` from bottom to top ? By *focus line* I mean the blue line on this picture:

[image]

How can I change the selection direction of a tab when it's aligned to bottom. I've succeeded changing the direction in my last project by aligning it and changing the text property, but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, you need to go to TabControl ----> TabPosition ----> Set position to tpBottom ----> Change Text property.

Focus line is on top now, cheers.